# PayPal Server SDK: how to approve an order ID

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I was trying to implement paypal api for one of my projects

I am using sandbox environment and server side sdk

In the request i have

```
{
    "intent": "CAPTURE",
    "application_context": {
      "brand_name": "EXAMPLE INC",
      "landing_page": "BILLING",
      "shipping_preference": "SET_PROVIDED_ADDRESS",
      "user_action": "PAY_NOW"
    },
```

i.e

```
"intent": "CAPTURE"
"user_action": "PAY_NOW"
```

I created an order using the api OrdersCreateRequest(). In the response i get the

```
result.id = "IDVALUE"
result.status = "CREATED"
```

and also the links

```
"links": [
    {
        "href": "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v2/checkout/orders/XXXXXXXX",
        "method": "GET",
        "rel": "self"
    },
    {
        "href": "https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/checkoutnow?token=XXXXXXXXXX",
        "method": "GET",
        "rel": "approve"
    },
    {
        "href": "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v2/checkout/orders/XXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
        "method": "PATCH",
        "rel": "update"
    },
    {
        "href": "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v2/checkout/orders/XXXXXXXXXXXXXX/capture",
        "method": "POST",
        "rel": "capture"
    }
],
```

I have tried to open the url

```
        {
            "href": "https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/checkoutnow?token=XXXXXXXXXX",
            "method": "GET",
            "rel": "approve"
        },
```

In the browser, it asks for PayPal login, what credentials we have to use as login and password. I have only `client_id` and `client_secret`

How to get an approved order id. What should I do now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The next step is to redirect the payer to that approval_url or use the Order ID with Smart Payment Buttons, which is better than redirecting.  Either way the payer will be signing in with their PayPal (sandbox) buyer account or entering their (sandbox) buyer information in a PayPal window or form.

The best approval flow to use is the one at https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server

Note that it pairs with two routes on your server, one that creates the order and one that captures the order after approval.

Comment: Yes ` it pairs with two routes on your server,` thats right

Comment: `use the Order ID with Smart Payment Buttons, which is better than redirecting` I will check this.

Comment: `The next step is to redirect the payer to that approval_url ` How to capture the response from here.

Comment: First of all don't do it, since it's a bad old style integration method. But if you were to be doing such a bad redirect integration, it goes to the return_url you specify.

Comment: Ok `use the Order ID with Smart Payment Buttons`. In this case how to get the response. Because based on this response, the order id and satus i have to start capture

Comment: From onApprove, call the second route on your server to do the capture.

Comment: When i am trying to use my localserver url in createOrder eg: `http//127.0.0.1/create_order` in fetch in the code in `https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server` in chromium, i get  `because it violates the document's Content Security Policy.`

Comment: @SanthoshYedidi
Same issue , i ve implemented a rest endpoint to complete this process at server side , I m using spring boot at backend .
How to approve the order in Java without redirecting the user to catpure and complete payment ? i didn't find official SDK example except with Smart Payment Buttons method or redirecting user when i call OrdersCreateRequest

Comment: Yes, its like a missing link. But its obvious, because to approve its as good as user has to login with credentials etc. So you know login will be another big api to create. I think thats the reason why they say to use smart button. But is smart button availabe in android also. or we have to use in webview.

Generally we first go throught the sdk and follow the steps. But here many few will go through smart button if they are creating their own api.

So @PrestonPHX is the saviour

Answer (score 0):

How to get the username and the password for the sandbox account.

Navigate to

[image]

And we see the email and password which can used to as paypal login credentials while  approve the order

[image]

So now go to the approve url `https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/checkoutnow?token=XXXXXXXXXX`

[image]

and click on login (paypal account) and enter email and password

[image]

[image]

And after successful login pay here

[image]

So now the order gets approved.